# Odd location for null reference exception

Tags: c#

I have the following code snippet:

```
1. var x = item.Current.DeepProperty;
2. var current = item.Current as IFoo;
3. if (current == null)
4.    continue
5. var y = item.Bar.Baz
```

Why am I getting a runtime `null reference exceptions` error on line 3?

I have the correct PDBs, the assembly is compiled in release mode with Optimization turned on.

### Update

I released an unoptimized version and found it was line 5 that was throwing.

Comment: Well, in release mode there's no guarantee that the code executing is exactly how you wrote it; treat the debug info as more of a guideline when optimizations are on. In this case, the exception is almost certainly due to `item.Current` on line 2.

Comment: I just ran into a scarily similar issue in a java application yesterday--NullPointerException on a line checking for null. I'm going to keep my eye on this--who knows, the answer might shed some light on my issue.

Comment: @Cameron, if `item.Current` is the problem, wouldn't the exception throw from line 1 before it ever got to line 2?

Comment: Looking at your question title I could not figure what you were talking about on "NRE". Could you please edit that? It makes no sense without the body of the question as context.

Comment: @Brian: Oops, of course you're right (barring weird shenanigans where `item.Current` changes value each time it's accessed). Come to think of it, though, the compiler/JITer could easily reorder those two lines...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 3 could not trigger a null reference exception.  The release build is optimizing your code which changes the line numbers.  If `item` or `item.Current` is `null` you *would* get that exception.

However, the optimizer usually *removes* lines from a build, so it's more likely that the exception is coming from a *later* line.

In order to find the *exact* source you'll need to reproduce the error in a Debug build.  Or add more null-checking and logging.

Comment: so presumably its line 1 thats throwing. What has the optimizer likely done to my code to cause this outcome?

Comment: Is it not possible for a poor implementation of the == operator to cause a NRE on line 3?

Comment: The optimizer can do pretty much anything it wants so long as the resulting code is equivalent.  There's no way to tell from the snippet you've posted. As suggested in comments, treat the line number as a rough guideline in Release mode.

Comment: @Rawling The _operator_ could throw that exception, but then the exception would be sourced from the operator code, not the calling code (unless the optimizer decided to inline the operator code, which seems odd)